# Serilog does not send logs to Elasticsearch 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog

I used **ELK** stack to log application errors, but **Serilog** does not log to **elasticsearch**.

The elasticsearch version that is used is **8.3.2**.

Log configuration in `program.cs`:

```
builder.UseSerilog((hostBuilder, serviceProvider, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    var appSettings = hostBuilder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Get<AppSettings>();

    CreateBasicLoggerConfiguration(loggerConfiguration)
        .WriteTo.File(logPath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour)
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(appSettings.ElasticsearchSettings.Uri))
        {
            IndexFormat = $"َapp-logs-{environment.EnvironmentName.Replace(".","-")}-{DateTimeOffset.Now.LocalDateTime:yyyy-MM}",
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true
        });
});
```

And, **elasticsearch** setting in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ElasticsearchSettings": {
  "Uri" : "http://localhost:9200"
}
```

The following packages were added and used:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" Version="1.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" Version="8.4.1" />
```

Everything looks ok but there is no log in elastichsearch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is because of the current version of `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch` serilog sink is not supported **elasticsearch version 8.*.**

By default, so you need some more configuration. I recently faced this issue and wrote an article about it. I recommend reading that article and solving your problem.

Try the following config:

```
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(appSettings.ElasticsearchSettings.Uri))
{
      IndexFormat = $"َapp-logs-{environment.EnvironmentName.Replace(".","-")}-{DateTimeOffset.Now.LocalDateTime:yyyy-MM}",
      AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
      OverwriteTemplate = true,
      TemplateName = yourTemplateName,
      AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
      TypeName = null,
      BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create
});
```

**Article Link** : [How to integrate Serilog with Elasticsearch 8 + Kibana](https://medium.com/@karimifard.milad/how-to-integrate-serilog-with-elasticsearch-8-b1e2ce656a28)

Comment: Along with this, setting `- ELASTIC_CLIENT_APIVERSIONING=true` on the elastic server is important.

Comment: This is not true any more.
`Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch` 9.x support elastic stack 8.*.
More info on the site: 
https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

[`Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch`](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch#features) in version 9.0 support elasticsearch version `8.*`

On the official site suggestion is to use `Elastic.Serilog.Sinks` package for ecs >= 8.x`

More info in [serilog-data-shipper](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/dotnet/current/serilog-data-shipper.html#serilog-data-shipper)

## Comparison with Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch

- Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch is an amazing community led sink that has a ton of options and works against older Elasticsearch versions < `8.0`.
- `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch` is unofficially supported by Elastic with some of the .NET team helping to maintain it.
- `Elastic.Serilog.Sinks` is officially supported by Elastic and was purposely build to adhere to newer best practices around logging, datastreams and ILM.
- `Elastic.Serilog.Sinks` is purposely build to have fewer configuration options and be more prescriptive than `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch`.
- That is not to say there aren’t plenty of configuration hooks in `Elastic.Serilog.Sinks`