# Serilog & Elastic Search aspnetcore with docker not working

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

I have installed both elastic search and kibana 8.6.1

[image]

I am using Serilog.AspnetCore 6.1, Serilog.Enrichers.Environment 2.2, and Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch 9.0

[image]

I have configured my application with Serilog to log data to elastic search

```
configuration
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.Enrich.WithMachineName()
.WriteTo.Debug()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticConfigurationSettings.Uri))
{
  IndexFormat = $"applogs-{context.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
  TypeName = null,
  AutoRegisterTemplate = true
})
.Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName ?? "Environment Missing")
.Enrich.WithProperty("Application", context.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName ?? "Application Unknown")
.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
```

Below is my Serilog settings in the appsettings.json file

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  }
```

I have an httphandler that has logging statements

```
logger.LogInformation("Sending request to {Url}", request.RequestUri);
logger.LogInformation("Received a success response from {Url}", response.RequestMessage.RequestUri);
```

but I never see any data in kibana. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to networking your containers with each other
you can using them by adding Container Orchestrator and making you're project multi-container app
see more information about it in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/)

Comment: I did create a network called “elastic” per the examples. I then provided the elastic token and logged into kibana with the elastic user. It appears my application is not depositing data if Im not mistaken. I have not containerized my application components only my data stores. I assume serilog should be able to send data to http://localhost:9200?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things working.

I changed

```
"ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  }
```

to

```
"ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://elasticsearch:9200"
  }
```

since this is the name of the container w/in docker.

I updated my docker-compose file to update a few settings within elasticsearch 8.6.1

```
- ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
- xpack.security.enabled=false
- discovery.type=single-node
- ELASTIC_CLIENT_APIVERSIONING=1
```

I updated my Kibana settings as well

```
- ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

In addition, I came across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057258/serilog-does-not-send-logs-to-elasticsearch-8) discussing Serilog and ES8, which helped me update my common logging library

I am now able to launch Kibana and see my logs.